# Create List with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, list, tree

I need some help to create a list with the following dataSource with the help of JavaScript, by using document.createElement("ul") , document.createElement("li"). All this needs to be done with JavaScript, not with JQUERY. The following is the code, but how to implement it with ul and li .

```
var dataSource = ({
            "Pen": ({
                "Cello":({}),
                "Parker":({})
                     })
                 });

function traverseObject(obj, level) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
      if(typeof obj[prop] == "object" ) {
            if(level == 0){
            listing.item(prop, level);
            }
            if(level == 1){
            listing.tree(prop, level);
            }
            console.log(prop + " - " + " level: " + level);
            traverseObject(obj[prop], level + 1);
      } 
        else {
//          output(obj[prop], level + 1);
//          console.log(obj[prop] + " - " + " level: " + level);
     }
    }
}

traverseObject(dataSource, 0);
```

Comment: where are you stuck as of now? The forum allows 'specific' code related questions only. So tell us about the code where you're stuck!

Comment: `All this needs to be done with JavaScript, not with JQUERY.` Then why did you tag this question with JQUERY.?

Comment: function traverseObject(obj, level) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
      if(typeof obj[prop] == "object" ) {
   if(level == 0){
   listing.item(prop, level);
   }
   if(level == 1){
   listing.tree(prop, level);
   }
      console.log(prop + " - " + " level: " + level);
            traverseObject(obj[prop], level + 1);
      } 
  else {
//   output(obj[prop], level + 1);
//   console.log(obj[prop] + " - " + " level: " + level);
     }
    }
}

traverseObject(dataSource, 0);

Comment: are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Ek2xS/1/

Comment: yes... this is the correct Jfiddle... thank you...can i add click expandable and close to each and every element??

Comment: updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ek2xS/18/. these kind of DOM manipulation is much smoother with jQuery.

Comment: thank you verymuch...excellent work

Comment: can you help me to sort it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursive tree building and sorting on the object:

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ek2xS/23/

html:

```
<div id="list"></div>
```

script:

```
var dataSource = ({
    "Pen": ({
        "Parker": ({
            "P1": ({}),
                "P2": ({})
        }),
            "Cello": ({
            "C2": ({}),
                "C1": ({})
        })
    })
}),
    traverseObject = function (obj) {
        var ul = document.createElement("ul"),
            li, span, sorted = [],
            i = 0;

        for (var prop in obj) {
            sorted.push(prop);
        }
        sorted.sort();
        for (; i < sorted.length; i++) {
            li = document.createElement("li");
            span = document.createElement("span");
            span.innerHTML = sorted[i];
            addListener(span, "click", function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                toggleList.call(this);
            });

            li.appendChild(span);
            if (typeof obj[sorted[i]] == "object" && Object.keys(obj[sorted[i]]).length) {
                li.appendChild(traverseObject(obj[sorted[i]]));
            }
            ul.appendChild(li);
        }
        return ul;
    },
    addListener = function (element, eventName, handler) {
        if (element.addEventListener) {
            element.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
        } else if (element.attachEvent) {
            element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, handler);
        } else {
            element['on' + eventName] = handler;
        }
    },
    toggleList = function () {
        var elem = this.nextSibling;
        if (elem && elem.nodeName == "UL") {
            if (elem.style.display == "none") elem.style.removeProperty("display");
            else elem.style.display = "none";
        }
    };

window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(traverseObject(dataSource));
}
```

regards